# Dynamically choosing starting text right after subsection title

Tags: sectioning

I already know how to display text right after subsection title using the `titlesec` package using this command:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
   {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

My problem is, using this format style, the text starts right after all the subsections. What can I do to use this command for some subsections and leave others? That is, the `subsection` will work normally in some cases and use the above command to display text right after it in some other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\runinsubsection{\@startsection {subsection}{1}{\z@}%
                               {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                               {-1em}%
                               {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\runinsubsection*{Special subsection}
Text starting right after subsection

\subsection*{Normal Sub-section}
This is a normal section.

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: how is the reader to tell that the run in subsection with smaller font and no vertical offset is at the same level of the section hierarchy and is not a subsubsection. Especially in the un-numbered form as used above?